# iOS11, Xcode 9, iPhone6 Plus, UIDeviceDidChangeOrientation notification not called,UIDevice.current.orientation only returns portrait

Tags: ios11, device-orientation, iphone-6-plus, xcode9-beta

Im using xcode 9, ios 11. I have an observer for UIDeviceOrientationDidChange and it works well on my 6s, but on the 6s Plus, it is not called when the device changes orientation, and checking UIDevice.current.orientation shows portrait at all times regardless of device position.

Anyone have any information about this?

Code is really basic

```
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showHideRotateOverlay), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

added in viewWillAppear. Works in ios 8, 9, 10.

Portrait and LandscapeRight are enabled in settings. this DOES WORK on previous ios versions

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code?  Also, when you first open Xcode, what are the settings there?  That initial screen in Xcode has a few radio boxes where you have the option to select your orientations.

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast ill post the code soon. its literally just basic notification center stuff. all of this works fine on ios 10. The initial settings are correct

Comment: This seems to have been solved in the final beta version recently released